# How to add error bars with standard deviation using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-deviation

I want to plot errorbars with standard deviation on my linear plot. I don't know why it is working with standard error only. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried few methods but I keep getting errors.

```
library(ggplot2)
line = ggplot(alldata, aes(Time, Vol))
line +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = 'point')+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = 1))+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5)+
```

When it's `mean_se` it's working, but I need `sd`

```
  ylab("V")+
  xlab("T)")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size=2))
```

- Time-x
- Vol-y
- alldata - data frame

I have my plot but with standard error bars only

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a minimal reproducible example. Learn from it and revise your question. Besides this, a great question is the one that reflects adequate research done. There is no dearth of similar questions asked earlier. So, when you post a question ensure to provide adequate documentation on what all steps you tried including similar questions like yours to find your solution.

In the absence of data, I use the `mtcars` dataset.

`mean_sdl` takes an argument `mult` which specifies the number of standard deviations - by default it is `mult = 2`. So you need to pass `mult = 1`

```
library(tidyverse)

#load mtcars dataset
mtcars <- mtcars
str(mtcars)
# coerce to factor for bar plot
mtcars$cyl<- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$gear<- as.factor(mtcars$gear)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, disp, fill = gear)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", na.rm = TRUE,
       position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", fun.data = "mean_sdl", 
            fun.args = list(mult = 1),
            position =  position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  ylab("mean displacement") +
  ggtitle("Some plot")
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. It was my first question, I'll improve next time.

Comment: @daria-cislo, if the proposed solution worked for you then accept it as an answer. This will help others looking at this question.